# How to get the list of NFT exist in my wallet?

Tags: web3js

As like trust-wallet gives the list of available NFT in the wallet.

How can we achieve that same thing?

What are the multiple ways to achieve that thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options

- Use a third party service that provide such listing.
- Run your own crawler and index all NFT transactions.
- Query through a contract a listing of popular NFT tokens.